# Как переделать цикл в массив?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь переделать цикл в массив, но не совсем понимаю, как это правильно сделать. Выкидывает ошибку:

> NegativeArraySizeException.

Цикл:

```
private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {

  StringBuilder stringWithSymbols = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {
    stringWithSymbols.append(symbol);
  }
  return stringWithSymbols.toString();
}
```

Массив:

```
    private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {

  char[] stringWithSymbols = new char[numberOfSymbols]; // NegativeArraySizeException
      Arrays.fill(stringWithSymbols, symbol);
      return new String(stringWithSymbols);

}
```

Comment: Значит numberOfSymbols < 0, можете добавить код, где вызывается данный метод?

Comment: Да вроде бы дебаг показывает, что stringWithSymbols получается такая же, как и в примере с циклом.
Вот строчка из другого метода, которая вызывает этот метод:
viewResult.append(String.format("%" + countTab(i, operation) + "s", assemblyString(operation.get(i).get(j).length(), '-'))).append("\n");